# Sharing sessions on domain and subdomains not working on android phone

Tags: php, android, apache, .htaccess, session-cookies

I use

```
php_value session.cookie_domain ".domain.com"
```

in .htaccess to share sessions on the domain and all subdomains and it's working, except from android phone

Why is that ? Is there any way forward here ?

Ps. It's also not working if session.cookie_domain = .domain.com directcly in php.ini - the site have a lot of pages so a .htacces or php.ini way would be preferable

Comment: I was also facing such an error once. You can try removing those cookies and adding them again. It might be bcoz they are set for a future time period. Edit: as it is session, you can wait session to end

Comment: You are actually right, it is old cached data causing this. Strange cookies survive both restarting browser and phone when session.cookie_lifetime = 0 in php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was old cached data causing this. Cookies survived both when restarting the browser and phone with session.cookie_lifetime = 0 in php.ini. Manually deleting all personal data was resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Session cookies are set when your client does not have any or if they expire. Unless you forcefully change their value (like name) they would not change. But some values like domain - we do not easily tend to forcefully change.

This means that if a session cookie is set for `+15 minutes` then you shall either wait 15 mins or use `session_destroy()` or cleaar cookies from your browser manually.

When the next cookie is set it shall work properly.

Comment: Sorry for such a late post buy I guess you should accept this answer as it may help someone else in future. @embe

Comment: Couldn't recognize the issue in this answer.